# Sorting according to time in string in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

How can i sort if my `time(time_required)` is saved in this format ?

```
quiz_customer_record

{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5f16eb4a5007bd5395c76ed9"),
    "quiz_id" : "5f05bbd10cf3166085be68fc",
    "user_id" : "5f06e0ddf718c04de30ea47f",
    "name" : "ABC",
    "time_required" : "0:6 Mins",
    "questions_attempted" : 0,
    "total_quiz_questions" : 1,
    "attempt_date" : "2020-07-21T13:19:08.025Z"
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5f16eb5f5007bd5395c76edb"),
    "quiz_id" : "5f05bbd10cf3166085be68fc",
    "user_id" : "5f06e0ddf718c04de30ea47f",
    "name" : "ABC",
    "time_required" : "0:8 Mins",
    "questions_attempted" : 0,
    "total_quiz_questions" : 1,
    "attempt_date" : "2020-07-21T13:19:29.377Z"
}
```

I want to sort it according to `time_required` but its in string and is in format of `Mins:Seconds`. Yes its a pretty messed up. But do we have a solution? I want to use mongo query for that as there are so many records and i sort of need to use limit(for pagination). That is why it is necessary for using mongo query.

Expected Result- Sort type- descending()

```
   {
        "_id" : ObjectId("5f16eb5f5007bd5395c76edb"),
        "quiz_id" : "5f05bbd10cf3166085be68fc",
        "user_id" : "5f06e0ddf718c04de30ea47f",
        "name" : "ABC",
        "time_required" : "0:8 Mins",
        "questions_attempted" : 0,
        "total_quiz_questions" : 1,
        "attempt_date" : "2020-07-21T13:19:29.377Z"
    },
   {
        "_id" : ObjectId("5f16eb4a5007bd5395c76ed9"),
        "quiz_id" : "5f05bbd10cf3166085be68fc",
        "user_id" : "5f06e0ddf718c04de30ea47f",
        "name" : "ABC",
        "time_required" : "0:6 Mins",
        "questions_attempted" : 0,
        "total_quiz_questions" : 1,
        "attempt_date" : "2020-07-21T13:19:08.025Z"
    }
```

The query i'm using is

```
 db.quiz_customer_record.aggregate([{ $match: { quiz_id:quiz_id}},
    {
        $sort: { attempt_date: -1 }
    },
    {
        $group: {
            _id: "$user_id",
            result1: { $first: "$attempt_date" },
            quiz_id: { $first: "$quiz_id" },
            time_required: { $first: "$time_required" },
             o_id: { $first: "$_id" }
        }
    },
    {
        $project: {
            _id: "$o_id",
            user_id: "$_id",
            quiz_id:"$quiz_id",
            time_required:"$time_required",
            result1: 1
        }
    }
]).sort({time_required:-1})
```

Comment: I don't know how to do this, but the best advice is to not use a string field where a number of date is really required.  Note that you can't even just sort on the portions before and after the colon.  You'd also have to cast those values to numbers first.

Comment: Yes, i have learned from this, and did a noob mistake which needs to be fixed.

Comment: Storing timestamp instead of string would be a great idea, to be able to perform DB operations like sorting, subtraction, addition, etc

Comment: You can use an aggregation query to transform the mins string to a `date` object, and then sort it. To convert use the aggregation operator - `$dateFromParts` - and use an arbitrary date values for all documents for the remaining arguments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer for mongo version less than 4.2

`$set` was added in 4.2 version. For earlier version `$addFields` can be used.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$addFields": {
      "time_required_split": {
        $substr: [
          "$time_required",
          0,
          3
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$addFields": {
      "time_required_split": {
        $split: [
          "$time_required_split",
          ":"
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$addFields": {
      "time_seconds": {
        $sum: [
          {
            "$multiply": [
              {
                $toInt: {
                  $arrayElemAt: [
                    "$time_required_split",
                    0
                  ]
                }
              },
              60
            ]
          },
          {
            $toInt: {
              $arrayElemAt: [
                "$time_required_split",
                1
              ]
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$sort": {
      time_seconds: -1
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      "time_required_split": 0,
      "time_seconds": 0
    }
  }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/KeIsl4AQty7)

Answer (score 1):

Try this query -

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$set": {
      "time_required_split": {
        $substr: [
          "$time_required",
          0,
          3
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$set": {
      "time_required_split": {
        $split: [
          "$time_required_split",
          ":"
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$set": {
      "time_seconds": {
        $sum: [
          {
            "$multiply": [
              {
                $toInt: {
                  $arrayElemAt: [
                    "$time_required_split",
                    0
                  ]
                }
              },
              60
            ]
          },
          {
            $toInt: {
              $arrayElemAt: [
                "$time_required_split",
                1
              ]
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$sort": {
      time_seconds: -1
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      "time_required_split": 0,
      "time_seconds": 0
    }
  }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/c-Z-qHDiHGO)

Let me know if don't understand any stage.

Comment: thankyou for this, can you explain the part why you used 0,3? @wak789

Comment: To convert `0:8 Mins` to `0:8`. Getting the sub string from 0th index to 3rd index (exclusive)

Comment: Ok, you are a genius! This worked for me. Thanks a lot :D

Comment: Hi, this works in Mongo playground, but when i run it on my server db version v4.0.17.
It throws this error - Error: command failed: {
 "ok" : 0,
 "errmsg" : "Unrecognized pipeline stage name: '$set'",
 "code" : 40324,
 "codeName" : "Location40324

Any thoughts?

Comment: Ohh... I will try to do it some other way. Give me some time.

Comment: I have posted another answer for versions less than 4.2

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223745/discussion-between-pse-and-wak786).